# Sci Fi Collection of Stories for younger readers

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I can only recall two of the stories:

One was about this machine that made edible soap and these children were addicted to eating it/ someone was also forcing them to eat the soap.

The other was about this girl who turned her boyfriend into a flightless and clawless bird after finding out his fear was not being able to have freedom.

I read this book around the 3rd grade so I don’t have the best memory but hopefully that’s helpful!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  We don't know when you were in 3rd grade, so the year you read this would really help.  Do you remember the cover of the book, or any illustrations you could describe?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! It was around 2011. I don’t recall the front cover, and I don’t remember there being any illustrations. Ive been searching for this book for a few years now and I just haven’t been able to find it, so I really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @Angelica Hey, you appear to have lost track of your original account.  You should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can add this detail to your question, respond to other comments, and accept an answer when one is posted.